# MongoStore.create({ ..............Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have tried every possible step I've come across but the problem doesn't resolve. The error shows:

```
C:\Users\...............\server.js:35
store: MongoStore.create({
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\..............\server.js:35:19)
```

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const app=express();
const ejs=require('ejs')
const path = require('path')
const expressLayout = require('express-ejs-layouts')
const PORT =process.env.PORT || 3300
const mongoose= require('mongoose')
const session = require('express-session')
const flash = require('express-flash')
const MongoStore=require('connect-mongo').default

//Database connection

const url='mongodb://localhost/pizza';
mongoose.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true, 
     useUnifiedTopology:true})
.then(()=>{
    console.log('Database connected...');
}).catch(error => {
    console.error('Connection failed...');
    console.error(error.message);
});//event listener

//Session store
// let  mongoStore= MongoDbStore({
//     mongooseConnection:mongoose.connection ,
//     collection: 'sessions'
// })
//Session Configuration
//session cant work without cookies so we use secret key for encrypting the cookies
app.use(session({
secret:process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
resave:false,
store: MongoStore.create({ 
    mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI 
}),
saveUninitialized:false,
cookie:{maxAge:1000*60*60*24} // time in milliseconds-equivallent to 24 hours
}));


app.use(flash());
//Assets
app.use(express.static('public'))

//set template engine
app.use(expressLayout)
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'/resources/views'))
app.set('view engine','ejs')

require('./routes/web')(app)



app.listen(PORT , ()=>{
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: If MongoStore is undefined then presumably `require('connect-mongo')` didn't give an object that has a default property... so did you check what it _is_?

Comment: Related: [TypeError: MongoStore is not a Constructor](/a/67809514/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced same issue today and I solved it by removing default

```js
// earlier
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo').default

//new
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')
```

And:

```js
app.use(session({
  store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI}),
  //process.env.MONGO_URI does not work for me instead of it I need to provide my database url manually
  ...options
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the `default` property from your `connect-mongo` import? The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo#usage) for the `connect-mongo` library seems to import `MongoStore` without it.

```js
// Your import
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo').default

// Their import
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')

//Change your connection as below to fix
//'You must provide either mongoUrl|clientPromise|client in options' error
app.use(
  session({
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI }),
    ...options
  })
);
```

Comment: Assertion failed: You must provide either mongoUrl|clientPromise|client in options
C:\Users\...........\realtime-pizza\node_modules\connect-mongo\build\main\lib\MongoStore.js:119
            throw new Error('Cannot init client. Please provide correct options');      
            ^

Error: Cannot init client. Please provide correct options